# Are there differences in the AppEngine Python SDK development server code between platforms?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sdk

I have created a buildout for a Pyramid project on GAE and as part of the buildout, it pulls http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/files/google_appengine_1.6.3.zip and places it in the project structure. This works fine for Linux and OS X (although of course extras like the Launcher are not present).

Are the Python code differences with the GAE Windows SDK such that I can't use the .zip file or is the developer server code the same between platform versions? (the differences just being extras and the install method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python code for the tools (dev_appserver and appcfg) are identical for all three platforms.

Comment: yep, we have a buildout using the rod.recipe.appengine, and the mac devs, and windows devs have had no issue with it. pretty amazing actually.